# Authenticator and PeerAuthenticator Not working Appengine endpoints

Tags: java, google-app-engine, authentication, google-cloud-endpoints-v2

After upgrading to V2 Endpoints my API's that used @peerAuthenticator failed to validate the peer. I did the tests with the @Authenticator and had the same problem, ignored the execution.

I've created a [repository on GitHub](https://github.com/Veberb/AppengineAuthenticator) to test with an empty application.

The repository was created through the steps of [google documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/tools/maven).

- After running the app `mvn appengine:run` you can request to 3 endpoints:

  - http://localhost:8080/_ah/api/myapi/v1/firstApiMethod (without any auth)
  - http://localhost:8080/_ah/api/myapi/v1/b (with `@authenticator`)
  - http://localhost:8080/_ah/api/myapi/v1/c (with `@peerAuthenticator`)
- API

  ```
  @Api(name = "myapi", version = "v1")
  public class YourFirstAPI {

      @ApiMethod(name = "firstApiMethod", path = "firstApiMethod", httpMethod = HttpMethod.GET)
      public TestObject a() {
          return new TestObject();
      }

      @ApiMethod(name = "b", path = "b", httpMethod = HttpMethod.GET, authenticators = {Authenticator.class})
      public TestObject b() {
          return new TestObject();
      }

      @ApiMethod(name = "c", path = "c", httpMethod = HttpMethod.GET, peerAuthenticators = PeerAuthenticator.class)
      public TestObject c() {
          return new TestObject();
      }
  }
  ```
- Authenticator

  ```
  public class Authenticator implements com.google.api.server.spi.config.Authenticator {

      @Override
      public User authenticate(HttpServletRequest arg0) throws ServiceException {
          throw new ServiceException(401, "unauthorized");
      }

  }
  ```
- PeerAuthenticator

  ```
  public class PeerAuthenticator implements com.google.api.server.spi.config.PeerAuthenticator{

      @Override
      public boolean authenticate(HttpServletRequest arg0) {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          return true;
      }

  }
  ```

Has anyone had the same problem? Any Solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You did not set your authenticator or peer authenticator in your `@Api` or `@ApiMethod` annotation. See [the Javadoc](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/java/javadoc/com/google/api/server/spi/config/Api.html#authenticators--).

Comment: I've set authentication in my second @apiMethod, it uses a class that implements Authenticator. The problem is that it is not running my Override method.